# Django and Django rest framework + email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, registration, email-validation

How could i achieve email functionality using drf as backeend and django to hit these apis.What i need how will user be confirm from django while using drf to send activation link.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to add the code to send the verification email when you register.

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode, urlsafe_b64encode
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from threading import Thread

class EmailRegisterView(APIView):

    """APIs for Email Registeration"""
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        """Signup with Email"""
        serializer = EmailRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ...
            user.save()
            
            // send verification link
            cur_token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
            email = urlsafe_b64encode(str(user.email).encode('utf-8'))

            # now send email
            mail_subject = 'Email Confirmation'
            message = render_to_string('emails/email_verification.html', {
                'site_url': settings.SITE_URL,
                'token': f'api/users/verify/{email.decode("utf-8")}/{cur_token}',
            })

            t = Thread(target=send_mail, args=(
                mail_subject, message, settings.EMAIL_FROM_USER, to_email))
            t.start()
            
            return Response({
                "success": True,
                "user": MemberSerializer(user).data
            }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And you can add the confirmation view.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('verify/<str:email>/<str:email_token>',
        verify_email, name="verify_token"),
    ...
]
```

Then the `verify_email` function verifies the token and redirects.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def verify_email(request, email, email_token):
    """Verify Email"""
    try:
        target_link = settings.CLIENT_URL + "/account/result?type=email_verified"
        if verify_token(email, email_token):
            return redirect(target_link)
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                "emails/email_error.html",
                {'success': False, 'link': target_link}
            )
    except BaseException:
        pass
```

Here is the `verify_token` function.

```
def verify_token(email, email_token):
    """Return token verification result"""
    try:
        users = Member.objects.filter(
            email=urlsafe_b64decode(email).decode("utf-8"))
        for user in users:
            valid = default_token_generator.check_token(user, email_token)
            if valid:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
                return valid
    except BaseException:
        pass
    return False
```

Comment: thanks but what i want is how to call an api made in drf and call it in django view of another app then i have to email verify.

Comment: Then it's not about the DRF. It's about the frontend.